# Send text messages from ios apps to server

Tags: ios

How to send text messages from ios apps to server via asihttrequest ? If anyone has an example code please help me . Really need help right now

Comment: What do you mean by send text messages?

Comment: give some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the post variable for this purpose.

```
formReq = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    formReq.delegate = self;
    [formReq setPostValue:MESSAGE forKey:@"key"];
    [formReq startSynchronous];
```

There are two delegate methods you need to implement

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

    NSLog(@"requestFinished: %@", [request responseString]);
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"oops: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks manujmv . how about if I want to display the message in textview on ios apps ? Is it use the same method ? Really appreciate your answer.

Comment: for message displaying in textview, u just do as: textView.text = MESSAGE;